# python TypeError: get_client_list() missing 1 required positional argument: 'limit'

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, web-services

[image: ClientModel]

[image: ListClientHandler]

I have added two arguments to the getclient function,
but why the compiler still prompts the missing limit，
someone help...

env:python3.5.2 + tornado + mysql5.7

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1467, in _execute
    result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/XPlan/handler/client_mgr_handler.py", line 14, in post
    client.ClientModel.get_client_list(offset,limit)
TypeError: get_client_list() missing 1 required positional argument: 'limit'
```

Comment: You need to instantiate `ClientModel` to use its method.

Comment: Oh my god,tks for your answer, I made one of the most low-level errors...

Comment: Next time you should post your code instead of a screenshot of the IDE :) Would be more easy to work with.

Comment: I remember. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can you try with this?

```
client.ClientModel().get_client_list(offset, limit)
```

`ClientModel()` allows you to create an instance of the class

Comment: I made one of the most low-level errors.. thank you..It works properly, thanks!

Comment: we all make it when we start :). Feel free to upvote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to the OPs problem, but **having to instantiate the class is crucial here** and the available error can be misleading.

My error was missing the parenthesis when instantiating like so:

```py
client = Client
```

The fix was:

```py
client = Client()
```

Maybe it will help someone!